# MediatR registiring query class in different class library not working

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mediatr

Using mediatr fresh .net6 project and everything works fine except when injecting queries in Program.cs I expected to register all Query classes with single line:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

but it does not work, I had to define explicitly;

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAllProductsQuery));
```

`GetAllProductsQuery.cs` file in a class library, it's in the same solution.

I expect it to registered via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Why is it not working, and how can I avoid defining each query cqrs class explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=net-7.0) returns the assembly where the current code is being executed, so if it is not called from assembly (library) where your query classes are placed then it will not register those (in this case it should return assembly with the top-level statement, i.e. `Program.cs`).

Try getting assembly from a class located in the class library containing the queries:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAllProductsQuery).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 1):

Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain.

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Try loading all assemblies in execution context to register in MediatR.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by such way

```
var stateAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("State");
var queriesAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Queries");
services.AddMediatR(stateAssembly, queriesAssembly);
```

Where "State" and "Queries" as example from my code is same name as class library where your query classes exists